# How to read all child data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i read all child data from Firebase.

```
 let ShopRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: “ShoppingMallLst”).child(“ShoppingMall1”)
      ShopRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in         
          if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
              for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                  if let data = data.value as? [String: Any] {          
                      let Description = data["Description"] as? String
                      let Floor = data[“Floor”] as? Int
                        ….
 
                  }
              }
          }
      })
```

But how can i read the data from child "ShopPath?"

[image]

Comment: Please lowercase vars. Uppercase is used for Class and Structure definitions.

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Links sometimes break and if that happens the question will not be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to firebase is to keep data in snapshots as long as you can. So in this case instead of casting items to dictionaries, which loose ordering or arrays that get more complex as the structure gets deeper, leverage DataSnapshots.

Here's the main function to read all shops in ShoppingMall1 - similar to the code in your question.

```
func readMallShops() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("ShoppingMallList").child("ShoppingMall1")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allShopsSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

        for shopSnap in allShopsSnap {
            let shop = ShopClass(withSnap: shopSnap)
        }
    })
}
```

Then a class that holds data about each shop. Note that I pass each snapshot in to initialize the class

```
class ShopClass {
    var name = ""
    var height = ""
    
    convenience init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        let name = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "ShopName").value as? String ?? "No Shop Name"
        print("Shop: \(name)")
        self.name = name
        let shopPathSnap = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "ShopPath")
        let shopChildSnap = shopPathSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for childDataSnap in shopChildSnap { //iterate over the array in ShopPath
            let height = childDataSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Height").value as! String
            print("  height: \(height)")
            self.height = height
        }
    }
}
```

And the output looks like this

```
Shop name: Test
  height: 1,180
Shop name: Test 2
  height: 2,000
```

I left off the other child nodes as if you can read height, you can read the rest. So this just assigns and prints out the shop name and height (as a string).

A suggestion as well. Arrays are not well suited for NoSql databases and their use is very situational (avoid if possible). If you're using an array, there's probably a better structure available.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i love coding, but i have poor idea for data structure, so what data structure is suit for the NoSql databases?

Comment: @Guy Firebase structures are determined by the queries you want to run against them - there is no 'best' as it's what's 'best for your data'. Take a look at [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and this classic [Arrays are evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). My question will work for your structure so if it helps or answers the question, be sure to to accept ti so it can help others. See [How to Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thx, your coding is easy to understand, but i have no time to study another data structure, so i will also use structure array to store the data. I want to reload the tableview after appending all data to array, and loading firebase data to array need few seconds, now i need to delay the tableview reload function. Another way to call reload function after the data  appended to array immediately? Plz

Comment: @Guy If you're in a situation where you are needing delays to work with asynchronous calls then you're going about it the wrong way. You should never need to delay - it should be seamless. Perhaps paginating would be in orders. Also, loading data from Firebase should rarely take several seconds. So how much data are you loading - are you using the structure shown in the question? If so, you should be able to load thousands of shops within a mall in less than a second. Last thing - see the loop in my answer `for shopSnap`? immediately following that loop, reload the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

child "ShopPath" has type [String: [String: String]]
you can try:

```
let ShopPath = data["ShopPath"] as? [String: [String: String]]
```

Comment: Is there any usage? it will return nil when i print(ShopPath)

Comment: I don't see any problem with my code, can you use [String: [String: Any]] instead?

Comment: @Guy This is close but won't work as the array indexes are integers. Also, if the structure gets deeper, trying to cast it as an array get wildly complex [Int: [String: [String: [Int: String]]] etc (ouch). So I would advice against that and keep your data as DataSnapshots - it will make your code much easier to maintain.